# CakePHP 3.x: saving one input into multiple tables

Tags: cakephp, save, cakephp-3.0

I´m sorry I have to ask again, but I´m struggling with saving one input into two tables.

**My first table:**

```
deceases
 - id
 - other records
 - funeral_id
 - cemetery_id
```

**My second table:**

```
funerals
 - id
 - other records
 - cemetery_id
```

**My third table:**

```
cemeteries
 - id
 - other records
```

**The associations:**

```
One decease belongs to a funeral. A funeral has many deceases.
One decease belongs to a cemetery. A cemetery has many deceases.
One funeral belongs to a cemetery. A cemetery has many funerals.
```

In the add-action of the DeceasesController I want to save the `cemetery_id` into `deceases` and into `funerals` with one only input.

The other inputs into deceases and funerals are saved very well, but I don´t understand the documentation of CakePHP how to save the `cemetery_id`, too.

**DeceasesController:**

```
public function add() {

        $decease = $this->Deceases->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $decease = $this->Deceases->patchEntity($decease, $this->request->data, [
                'associated' => [
                    'Funerals', 
                    'Cemeteries' 
                ]
            ]);
            if ($this->Deceases->save($decease)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Saving successfully.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('Saving wasn´t successful. Try again.'));
            }
        }

        $cemeteries = $this->Deceases->Cemeteries->find('list', ['limit' => 300]);
        $funerals = $this->Deceases->Funerals->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('decease', 'cemeteries', 'funerals'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['decease']);
    }
```

**Snippet of add.ctp:**

```
echo $this->Form->input('funeral.cemetery_id', ['options' => $cemeteries, 'label' => 'cemetery']);
```

I hope, you´re able to understand my issue. English isn´t my first language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I have understood your question:

In your controller right after `patchEntity` and before saving you can do

```
$decease->cemetery_id = $decease->funeral->cemetery_id;
```

So the same value will be set both for decease and for funeral

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so so so much. <3